# Never show back button with "back" as title

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, cocoa

I have the back buttons translated to german ("Zurück"). However, it seems that when there isn't enough space (because of the length of the title) it is shown as "back". And if there is only very little space, no title is shown at all, only the chevron "<".

Is there a way for it to not show the back buttons with the "back" title, but only as "<" **if there isn't enough space for "Zurück"**?

Comment: If you know what's the max length allowed, you could rename your VC's title before the push the other VC to `@""`;

Comment: @Larme I have a very large amount of views and several formats. I really would like to avoid that solution.

Comment: Did u try this self.navigation.navigationBar.backItem.title = @"<";

Comment: @Shashi3456643 that would set the title to ``<`` and you would end having the back arrow and the minus sign as the button title.

Comment: @amb u r right I didn't understand question completely.

Comment: why did I get downvotes? Isn't it  a legit question? is it not correctly explained?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can override `loadView` and put this code in your view controller:

```
self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:nil action:nil];
```

You could calculate the text length before that in order to decide if you want to show the back button with title or without it.

**Edit**

It's better to do this in a `UIViewController` superclass and have all your view controllers extend that class.

Comment: As described [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11031426/386738). It would also set the title of subviews. Which means I would have to do it on every single `UIViewController`. Isn't there a way where I only have to do it on the first UIViewControllers? (I have a lot, and I'm lazy)

Comment: @simpleBob you can create a subclass of ``UIViewController``, make all your view controllers subclass of that class and implement the logic once in your parent class (override ``loadView`` or ``viewWillAppear`` and put your logic there).

Answer (score 0):

```
[[UIBarButtonItem appearance] setBackButtonTitlePositionAdjustment:UIOffsetMake(0, -60)
                                                             forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

Then you can remove the back button item title.

If you use Storyboard, you can set navigation attributes inspector Back Button with space.

[You can follow this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19078995/removing-the-title-text-of-an-ios-7-uibarbuttonitem)

Comment: Appearance proxy modifies all the ``UIBarButtonItem`` back button instances, and thus you cannot have the condition to decide to hide or not the back button text.

Comment: I want to show the translated button title if there is enough space