# Remove UINavigationBar back button title

Tags: ios, uinavigationbar

Is there a way to remove the title of back button items in **all** view controllers of an app?

---

*Note*: The important thing is the **all** word. The closest I've been is with [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20986544/1357853):

```
[[UIBarButtonItem appearance] setBackButtonTitlePositionAdjustment:UIOffsetMake(0, -60)
                                                     forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

but as I mention in the comment there's an issue with large titles being pushed to the right so that this solution is not valid.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just set the `title` of the back button to `""`

Here's a example in swift

```
self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(
        title: "",
        style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.Plain,
        target: nil,
        action: nil)
```

To do it in all the view controllers, i usually make a `BaseViewController` where i include that line in the `viewDidLoad` method. Then when i have a viewcontroller i subclass it to the `BaseViewController`.

Your solution could work if you also move the x value -150, but for me it sounds like hack because you are still showing it all the time, but off the view bounds.

Comment: +1 for giving a valid solution, though having to extend all view controllers from a custom one is quite annoying. More, I'll have to implement `UITableViewController` custom class too. But nice approach, thank you

Comment: Well you can make a ```UIViewController Extension``` (category in obj-c) with a method ```removeTitleFromBackButton()``` and then call ```self.removeTitleFromBackButton()``` in the viewControllers.

Comment: Finally accepted this answer as the only feasible. Thank you @IbrahimYildirim

Answer (score 3):

try with this

```
self.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = YES;
```

to hide explicit(that you set yourself) back button

```
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = nil;
```

Comment: That hides the back button, not the back button **title**

Comment: in your case you can set nil / empty string to remove the title

Comment: would you give me an image

Comment: I'm explicitly saying that I want to hide the title and only the title in all view controllers of the app

Comment: if you back button hide but did not hide title? how it is possible? It is impossible? so would you please share an image?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/93087/discussion-between-jamil65able-and-sonxurxo).

Answer (score 0):

One way of doing this that hasn't been mentioned is to use a custom tile view that displays the title in a label and then never actually setting the title property of the ViewControllers.

This should be set up in either an extension of the UIViewController or a base class.

Then you don't have to change the barButtonItem at all and you have options to do more changes to the title (with subtitles etc.)

Something like this:

```
extension UIViewController {

    func setTitleView(title:String) {
        let titleView = CustomTitleView()
        titleView.titleLabel.text = title
        self.navigationItem.titleView = titleView
    }
}
```

If you set up a simple CustomTitleView nib with one label outlet and some constraints.

Edit:

Title property needs to be set to " " on all the VC. That way the back buttons text in the next pushed VC will be titled "  "

Comment: I can't see how that affects the back button

Comment: Back buttons title is set from previous view controllers title property. If the title is " " the buttons text is " ". I did forget to mention the title property needs to be set to " " though

Answer (score 0):

All you need to change the title of the back button of a `UINavigationController` is:

**Swift**:

`navigationController?.navigationBar.topItem?.title = ""`

You can add this to `viewWillAppear` of the new viewController being pushed or in a custom base class of `UIViewController`.