# UINavigationController not showing custom back button image on one screen

Tags: ios

I have a parent view controller that sets up the navigation bar with a custom back image and a right bar button item.  For some reason one individual screen which is pushed by two different controllers doesn't show the back button image until I press it.  Then it's there for good.  Anyone come across this?  Here is my button code being called in view did load.

```
// In my app delegate 
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    // Setup custom back button
    UIImage *backButton = [UIImage imageNamed:@"backButton"];
    [[UIBarButtonItem appearance] setBackButtonBackgroundImage:[backButton resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, backButton.size.width, 0, 0)]
                                                          forState:UIControlStateNormal
                                                        barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];

}

// In the parent view controller that all of the others inherit from
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // Custom Back Button
    UIBarButtonItem *backButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]
                                   initWithTitle: @" "
                                   style: UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered
                                   target: nil action: nil];

    [self.navigationItem setBackBarButtonItem: backButton];

}
```

This works fine on all screens except one no matter which VC it's pushed from.  But the one has a hidden image until the button is pressed.

Comment: you are always using push segues, right? no modals?

Comment: Yup.  That's what's so weird to me.

Comment: Try using `[self.navigationItem setLeftBarButtonItem:backButton];`

Comment: Wouldn't that remove my back functionality.  So as it seems it's everything that inherits from this parent class that are effected.  But any other controller that I explicitly put this code in is fine.  Not sure, I've obviously screwed something up.

Comment: Actually as it seems in only works for the first screen.  All the other screens are fine when I go back.  But the first time they show up nothing is there.

Comment: So apparently setting this up in viewDidLoad doesn't take on the first screen presentation.  So basically VC2 isn't showing the back button set by VC1 until the second time the viewWillAppear/viewDidAppear methods are called.

Comment: And it's only a problem in iOS 7

Comment: This appears to be a pretty broad problem.  Here is another question about it:  http://stackoverflow.com/q/18099073/793607

Comment: Yeah, now that I understand what the problem is I'm finding more about it.  Not thrilled with the idea of method swizzling and having to implement the back button myself, but I guess it is what it is.

Comment: iOS 7-- its not a bug, its a *feature*

Comment: Are you sure that the back button is in UIControlStateNormal?